# STRANGE: Password protected zip file from iCloud changes it's format once backed up, not able to unzip them

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I am uploading a password protected zip file as a backup to iCloud, it gets uploaded and then I download, unzip and use the same file, it works perfectly fine only if we are doing all these cool stuffs from the same device.

Consider this scenario,
1. zip and upload the file from one device.
2. download and unzip it from other device (Cannot unzip as it does not recognize that file is in zip format)

Note:
I have cross verified that file gets successfully downloaded in other device by enabling my iTunes file sharing.

But I am not able to unzip the file.

Comment: How did you determine that the format was changed?

Comment: What is meant by "format"? Also SO is about coding not general user questions.

Comment: @zaph it is a code question,I am zipping a file from my code uploading it to iCloud after making it password protected.

Comment: @zaph By format, I mean I can see the zip file after downloading from iCloud, but unzipping is giving me a problem, and thats why I say the format of file might have got changed.

Comment: @zaph By highlighting is as Strange, I mean if I do all these stuff from the same device that is password protect a zip, upload, download, unzip and use it works fine, the problem comes when you try to download the uploaded zip file in other device and then unzipping it.

Comment: If it is a "it is a code question,I am zipping a file from my code" add the code and example data, preferably of a small file or at least some portion. You need to provide a [mcve]. There is insufficient information to provide help. Also, note that there are two commenters: zneak and zaph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution by myself hope this will save someone else time, converting password protected zip file into data and uploading, downloading, unzipping the same**

Any file can be uploaded to iCloud container of any size (yes you should be having that much of space in iCloud) lets take an example SampleData.zip

```
// 1 This method will upload or sync SampleData.zip file in iCloud container, iCloud actually checks the metadata of your file before it uploads it into your iCloud container (so for first time it will upload the file and from next time it will only upload the changes)

-(void) iCloudSyncing:(id)sender
{
    //Doc dir
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.zip"];
    NSURL *u = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u];

    //Get iCloud container URL
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];// in place of nil you can add your container name
    //Create Document dir in iCloud container and upload/sync SampleData.zip
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.zip"];
    Mydoc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    Mydoc.zipDataContent = data;

    [Mydoc saveToURL:[Mydoc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"SampleData.zip: Synced with icloud");
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"SampleData.zip: Syncing FAILED with icloud");

     }];
}



  // 2 Download data from the iCloud Container

- (IBAction)GetData:(id)sender {

    //--------------------------Get data back from iCloud -----------------------------//
    id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
    if (token == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"ICloud Is not LogIn");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ICloud Is LogIn");

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];// in place of nil you can add your container name
        NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.zip"];
        BOOL isFileDounloaded = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:ubiquitousPackage error:&error];
        if (isFileDounloaded) {
            NSLog(@"%d",isFileDounloaded);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            //changing the file name as SampleData.zip is already present in doc directory which we have used for upload
            NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RecSampleData.zip"];
            NSString* fileAtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            NSData *dataFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ubiquitousPackage];
            BOOL fileStatus = [dataFile writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
            if (fileStatus) {
                NSLog(@"success");
            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%d",isFileDounloaded);
        }
    }
}

//3 voila its done :)
```